# What is Prof McGonagall's favourite Quidditch team?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

Ron Weasley's Quidditch team is the Chudley Cannons and Ginny's is the Holyhead Harpies, so what is McGonagall's?

Comment: Hey if you can spell McGonagall right in the title, why can't you spell it right in the question?  (I actually don't know how to spell it too, so it's okay :-)

Comment: Gryffindor maybe?

Answer (score 6):

According to Pottermore, it is the Montrose Magpies:

> Hobbies
>
> Needlework, correcting articles in Transfiguration Today, watching Quidditch, supporting the Montrose Magpies
>
> https://www.pottermore.com/fact-file-characters/minerva-mcgonagall-fact-file